# $L$ is Galois and $a \in K \implies L=K(\sqrt{a})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

**Question:** Suppose $K$ is a field of *characteristic* $\neq 2$ and $L$ is a *quadratic* extension of $K$. Prove that $L$ is *Galois* over $K$ and there is an $a \in K$ such that $L=K(\sqrt{a})$

---

**First part ($L$ over $K$ is Galois)**

I found the solution given here to be helpful: [Extensions of degree two are Galois Extensions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282249/extensions-of-degree-two-are-galois-extensions)
Let $L/K$ be field extension of degree $2$. $L $ \ $K \implies p(t)=min_K(\alpha, t)$ has degree 2 and splits over $L$

The only part I was unsure about is why does $p'(t) \neq 0$ imply separability?

---

**Second part (there is an $a$ such that $L=K(\sqrt{a})$**

I thought that if char$K \neq 2$ then any any cyclic quadratic extension of $K$ is of the form $L=K(\sqrt{a})$ so I though all elements in our example would have this property?

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, it might be helpful to look at the quadratic equation. This is an explicit formula for both of the roots of a polynomial in terms of its coefficients, and so you you need to show how to construct, as a field element, one root from the other

Answer (score 0):

**First part**

You have to first prove that a monic polynomial $f$ over a field $F$ has repeated roots over a splitting field $K$ iff $\gcd(f,f')$ is not a unit, where $f'$ is the formal derivative. This involves looking at the formal derivative of the factorized form of $f$ over $K$. The simplest way is via the product rule for the formal derivative, which you can prove before that.

After that, prove that if $f$ is irreducible, then $\gcd(f,f')$ is a unit iff $f' \ne 0$. This follows by expanding definitions, because $f'$ has strictly lower degree than $f$.

**Second part**

$K,L$ are **given**, and the question hence asks for you to **find** some $a \in K$ such that $L = K(\sqrt{a})$. Clearly not all $a \in K$ work, since $K(\sqrt{1}) = K \ne L$.
$\def\less{\smallsetminus}$

However, it is true that $L = K(b)$ for any $b \in L \less K$, since the only possible finite extension of $K$ within $L$ is $L$ itself.