# Galois extension $\mathbb Q(1/2+\sqrt{-3}/2)/\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, galois-theory

I have this exercise:

Determine whether the extension $\mathbb Q(1/2+i\sqrt{3}/2)/\mathbb Q$ is Galois.

If we call $\alpha=1/2+i\sqrt{3}/2$, then we find $\alpha^2-\alpha+1=0$. Its roots are $1/2+i\sqrt{3}/2$ and $1/2-i\sqrt{3}/2$ and therefore this extension is separable and the splitting field of this polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$. Now I think I should prove both roots are inside $\mathbb Q(1/2+i\sqrt{3}/2)$.

The first root is obvioulsly in; now if we square $((1/2+i\sqrt{3}/2)^2=-1/2+i\sqrt{3}/2=-(1/2-i\sqrt{3}/2)$, so the second root also is in and then the extension is Galois.

Could we correct or improve this proof?

Thanks

Comment: It is fine. Alternatively: $\mathbb Q(1/2+i\sqrt{3}/2)=\mathbb Q(i\sqrt{3})$ and the roots of $X^2+3$ are mutual opposites.

Comment: See also [Extensions of degree two are Galois Extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282249) or simply: if $\alpha$ is a root of $X^2+pX+q$ then the other root is $-p-\alpha.$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct,
but don't forget that when obtaining one root from another,
you can also add and multiply by the rational numbers.

In your case, let $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}$.
Then $-\alpha+1=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}$.
You don't necessarily have to square $\alpha$ every time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: @electr0n No problem. Consider accepting the answer if you find it helpful.